# Rationale in selecting Hash Key type

Tags: c++, string, integer, hashtable, key

Guys, I have a data structure which has 25 distinct keys (integer) and a value. I have a list of these objects (say 50000) and I intend to use a hash table to store/retrieve them. I am planning to take one of these approaches.

1. Create a integer hash from these 25 integer keys and store it on a hash table. (Yeah! I have some means to handle collisions)
2. Make a string concatenation on the individual keys and use it as a hash key for the hash table. For example, if the key values are 1,2,4,6,7 then the hash key would be "12467".

Assuming that I have a total of 50000 records each with 25 distinct keys and a value, then will my second approach be a overkill when it comes to the cost of string comparisons it needs to do to retrieve and insert a record?

Some more information!

1. Each bucket in the hash table is a balanced binary tree.
2. I am using the boost library's hash_combine method to create the hash from the 25 keys.

Comment: I presume this is C++ then, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely use the first method, because if you use the second , you will require a hash table which has `1x10^(25m), where x is the maximum length of a key`  slots available.

For example, if the maximum number a key can be is 9999, `m` would be 4 and you'd need 1x10^100 slots in your table.

---

**Explanation:**

The idea behind a hash table is that you can randomly access any element with an efficiency of O(1) (collisions aside) because any element's hash *is infact its position in the hash table*. So for example, if I hash Object X and a hash of 24 is returned (or some string hash which is converted to a number, which turns out to be 24), I simply go to slot 24 of my table (often implemented as an array), and can retrieve Object X.

But if you were using your second method (concatenating 25 numbers - we'll say digits to simplify things here - together to make the hash), the largest hash would be 9999999999999999999999999. Therefore to retrieve that object from the hash table, you'd have to retrieve it from position 9999999999999999999999999 - which means your table must have at least that many spots.

---

And remember, with the first one - since you're using a binary tree, collisions won't really be that big a deal. Worst case scenario will be a retrieval/insertion efficiency of O(log(n)) which isn't really that bad anyways.